# Qt isVisible() before setVisible()?

Tags: c++, qt

If we don't know if a Qt element is visible or not, is it preferable to check if it is before using `setVisible()` function?

Is there any performance difference even if not important?

```
if (ui->elem->isVisible() == false)
    ui->elem->setVisible(true);
```

Comment: On what platform you want to perform profiling?

Comment: @KamilKlimek I'm using GNU/Linux, currently Debian

Comment: valgrind, oprofile. QtCreator has "run and profile" option built-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided the check the 4.8.0 source - it's not hard to do. The answer appears to be that it'll make almost no difference to check first, but profiling will be the only way to know for sure.

```
void QWidget::setVisible(bool visible)
{
    if (visible) { // show
        if (testAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_ExplicitShowHide) && !testAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_Hidden))
            return;
        Q_D(QWidget);
        //...
    } else { // hide
        if (testAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_ExplicitShowHide) && testAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_Hidden))
            return;
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the function will directly return if the element is already visible. Next time I will try to check myself. What is the best way to do profiling?

Comment: Wish I knew... I haven't found one I like yet. Search around SO for options.

Comment: If someone wants a direct link to full Qt 4.8 source, it can be checked online from official repository: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/raw/efcbcd3e23b530443b55374e63db39e27b21ad9c/src/gui/kernel/qwidget.cpp

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. You can look at the Qt source to see for yourself.

Comment: maybe they are handling the isVisible check inside the setVisible function?